# Extract values of a pairwise matrix given similar samples names

Tags: r, matrix

Imagine a pairwise distance matrix formed by several samples, some of which have replicates, i.e. a sample with the same name except for _r at the end of it, and some which not. The matrix obviously gives the distance between all the pairs of samples, replicates or not. What I am interested in is only in the value between each of the sample-replicate pairs.

For example given a matrix with samples such as:

```
          Sample1  Sample1_r Sample2 Sample2_r Sample3
Sample1      0        79       111     113      110
Sample1_r    79       0        110     112      109
Sample2      111      110      0       80       115
Sample2_r    113      112      80      0        117
Sample3      110      109      115     117      0
```

Ideally I would like to obtain a dataframe with:

```
Sample1 79
Sample2 80
```

How can I extract this in an easy to repeat way? I have several matrices and they are all different, so I can't do it by position. I know I should use `grep` but beyond that my creativity is null now. Help much appreciated.

Example with dput

```
m<-structure(c(0, 79.0003888816214, 111.103209038065, 113.10726184344, 110.411316165512, 79.0003888816214, 0, 110.512687922526, 112.516740727902, 109.820795049973, 111.103209038065, 110.512687922526, 0, 80.1995887790629, 115.32854184629, 113.10726184344, 112.516740727902, 80.1995887790629, 0, 117.332594651665, 110.411316165512, 109.820795049973, 115.32854184629, 117.332594651665, 0), .Dim = c(5L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(c("Sample1", "Sample1_r", "Sample2", "Sample2_r", "Sample3"), c("Sample1", "Sample1_r", "Sample2", "Sample2_r", "Sample3")))
```

Comment: How about sharing a `dput` of the example you've provided here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
example <- matrix(data=c(0,79,111,113,110,79,0,110,112,109,111,110,0,80,115,113,112,80,0,117,110,109,115,117,0),nrow=5,ncol=5,dimnames=list(c("Sample1","Sample1_r","Sample2","Sample2_r","Sample3"),c("Sample1","Sample1_r","Sample2","Sample2_r","Sample3")))

> example
Sample1 Sample1_r Sample2 Sample2_r Sample3
Sample1         0        79     111       113     110
Sample1_r      79         0     110       112     109
Sample2       111       110       0        80     115
Sample2_r     113       112      80         0     117
Sample3       110       109     115       117       0

row.ind <- grep("_r",rownames(example),value=TRUE)
col.ind <- match(sub("_r","",row.ind),colnames(example))
your.df <- data.frame(sample=colnames(example)[col.ind],
                      dist=diag(example[row.ind,col.ind])
                     )

> your.df
   sample dist
1 Sample1   79
2 Sample2   80
```

Comment: Please format your code in a more sensible way. Readability is more important than saving lines.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach that uses a matrix to extract the desired values.

Convert your `dist` object to a `matrix` if necessary. Your sample data is already just class `matrix`, so in this case, `as.matrix` is not necessary. Then, use `grep` to find the `rownames` you're interested in, and `strsplit` to get the relevant `colnames`. Use the resulting matrix to subset from your original matrix.

```
## m <- as.matrix(m) # if your object is actually a `dist` matrix
row_names <- grep("_r", rownames(m), value=TRUE)
toget <- cbind(row_names, col_names = unlist(strsplit(row_names, "_r")))
m[toget]
# [1] 79.00039 80.19959
```

The output as a `data.frame`:

```
data.frame(toget, value = m[toget])
#   row_names col_names    value
# 1 Sample1_r   Sample1 79.00039
# 2 Sample2_r   Sample2 80.19959
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

```
rn <- rownames(m)
sapply(rn[grepl("_r$",rn)], function(x)m[x,substr(x,1,nchar(x)-2)])
```

Result

```
Sample1_r Sample2_r 
 79.00039  80.19959
```